# Not able to validate an XML document. "xs:schema" Must Not Contain The '<' Character

Tags: xml, xsd

I am not able to validate my XML document. I am getting an error saying `The Value Of Attribute "xmlns:xs" Associated With An Element Type "xs:schema" Must Not Contain The '<' Character.` I don't find any syntax errors in the code.

This is my XML code:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<bookstore>
 <book>
  <title>The Hunger Games</title>
  <author>Suzzanne Collins</author>
  <price>299</price>
 </book>
 <book>
  <title>Divergent</title>
  <author>Veronica Roth</author>
  <price>399</price>
 </book>
 <book>
  <title>Me Before you</title>
  <author>JoJoMoyes</author>
  <price>299</price>
 </book>
</bookstore>
```

and this is the XSD document:

```html
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema>
 <xs:element name="bookstore">
  <xs:complexType>
   <xs:sequence>
    <xs:element name="book" maxOccurs="unbounded">
     <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>  
        <xs:element name="title" type="xs:string"/>
        <xs:element name="author" type="xs:string"/>
        <xs:element name="price" type="xs:integer"/>
      </xs:sequence>
     </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
  </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
 </xs:schema>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Second line of your schema is

```
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema>
```

You're missing the closing quote, it should be

```
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
```